# Cannot access Bitnami Stack LimeSurvey application (hosted on AWS ec2 instance) via browser after changing IP address

Tags: ip-address, bitnami, static-ip-address, limesurvey

Please forgive me if this question is a bit ignorant (I am learning).

I have a Bitnami Stack for LimeSurvey hosted on an AWS ec2 instance. Everything was working as expected until I changed the `IPv4 Public IP` to an Elastic IP address. I did this as a first step in getting an SSL certificate for my LimeSurvey.

I can now no longer access the LimeSurvey via my browser (with, for example, `3.249.162.237/index.php/admin/authentication/sa/login` to log in). The error I get in my browser is: `Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at <<IP_ADDRESS>>`.

I can still log on to the Bitnami Stack for Limesurvey via SSH, after having changed the Public DNS (IPv4) to the new elastic IP address.

I am assuming that I need to change a file on the Bitnami Stack for Limesurvey so that I can access the LimeSurvey app via a browser (and so that others can as well, in order to complete surveys). However, I cannot figure out how to do this, and cannot find documentation for this specific problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens if you try to access it with curl?

Comment: Thanks for offering to help, but I got it figured out with a different method (see below). Sorry to have wasted your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the `sudo /opt/bitnami/bnsupport-tool` command on the Bitnami AWS instance, and the `bnsupport-tool` indicated that the instance certificate (`/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt`) and private key (`/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key`) did not match.

So, I had to generate a new SSL certificate and private key for the instance following [these instructions](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/trac/administration/create-ssl-certificate-apache/) in the Bitnami documentation. This solved the problem - I was able to regain access to the LimeSurvey app via a browser (and I only needed to create a temporary self-signed SSL certificate to do this).

I hope this helps anyone who was as lost as I was (also, general note, the [Bitnami Community](https://community.bitnami.com/) is probably the best place to start for these kinds of problems)!